# How to do reverse DNS lookup in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx configuration where I want to allow a DNS name as I cant be certain on IP address.

```
{
 satisfy any;
 allow www.domain.com; // want to achieve this
}
```

With Nginx we cant achieve this.

- Looked at this https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns as a solution.
  This module says it does reverse lookup but it didnt work and repo is very old and well maintained.
- Another alternative is to use a shell script and do a dig or host on IP address but we dont want to use shell script with Nginx.
- Alternate solution is to use a side car to do the DNS resolution and to add allow/deny rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this still works you'll need to compile it for the same version of nginx that is installed. If you're using nginx from a repo then dynamically compile it and see if the following helps:

Download nginx src matching installed version and extract it.

```
$ cd nginx-1.x.x
$ ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/path/to/nginx_module
$ make modules
```

make modules should  result in a nginx module that you need to copy to  `/usr/lib/nginx/modules/` and load it with `load_module modules/modulename.so` in your nginx.conf.

Comment: I had to download Nginx source code and built it , then need to do build module. But this module does not work as expected.